# Jest truncates list of received mock calls

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a test that calls a spy multiple times:

```
// example.test.js
it("Fails but doesn't log all calls", () => {
  const spy = jest.fn();
  spy("1");
  spy("2");
  spy("3");
  spy("4");
  spy("5");
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("not 1");
});
```

Jest truncates the output, so only the first 3 calls are listed under `Received`:

```
// jest example.test.js
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: "not 1"
Received
        1: "1"
        2: "2"
        3: "3"

Number of calls: 5

  10 |   spy("4");
  11 |   spy("5");
> 12 |   expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("not 1");
      |               ^
  13 | });
  14 |
```

How can I get the full list of calls to show in the terminal for assertion failures?

```
Received
        1: "1"
        2: "2"
        3: "3"
        4: "4"
        5: "5"
```

Comment: `spy.mock.calls`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of **June 2022**, it is not possible using built-in [jest assertions](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/719e8ea240421abdb95c244f01878eb6cfef61f9/packages/expect/src/spyMatchers.ts#L34):

```
const PRINT_LIMIT = 3
```

**Workaround:** Write a custom assertion error. See `logCalls`:

```
import { printReceived } from "jest-matcher-utils";

const logCalls = (spy) => {
  const receivedCalls = spy.mock.calls.map((call, i) => 
    `${i}: ${printReceived(call)}`
  )
  console.error(`All Received:\n${receivedCalls.join("\n")}`)
}

it("Fails and logs all calls", () => {
  const spy = jest.fn();
  spy("1");
  spy("2");
  spy("3");
  spy("4");
  spy("5");

  try {
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("not 1");
  } catch (e) {
    logCalls(spy)
    throw e
  }
});
```

Which will output the following error:

```bash
All Received:
    0: ["1"]
    1: ["2"]
    2: ["3"]
    3: ["4"]
    4: ["5"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just log to your console the mock calls"

```js
const spy = jest.fn();
  spy("1");
  spy("2");
  spy("3");
  spy("4");
  spy("5");

  console.log(spy.mock.calls)
```

**DOCS ->** https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions